# Proving that a map is differentiable

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, differentiation

Let $H$ be a self-adjoint operator on $\mathcal{H}$, $\psi\in D(H)$ and $\beta\geq 1/2$. How can I see that
$$ L \colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathcal{L}(D(\mathcal{N^\beta}),D(\mathcal{N^{\beta-1/2}})), \quad t\mapsto a\left( e^{iHt}\psi\right)$$
is differentiable?
Here $\mathcal{N}$ denotes the number operator and $a$ the annihilation or creation operator. (it should be true for both.)

Comment: Can you add for completeness the linear relations between $a, \mathcal{N}, H$?

Comment: I hope i understand you question right: we defined the annihilation and creation operators on the domain of the squareroot of the number operator: $(a^\dagger(\psi),D(\mathcal{N}^{1/2}))$ and $(a(\psi),D(\mathcal{N}^{1/2}))$.